# ProgressDialog not poping up

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to add a spinning progress dialog while the application is saving data. I have tried putting the code inside an `AsyncTask` but an error occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Besides, `AddEditProcessor` also extends `AsyncTask` and I need to use its result to determine different action, so I must use `.get()`. However, the log shows "dialog is running" but in fact nothing pops up actually!

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.note_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.save: 
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.show();
        Log.d(TAG, "dialog is running");

        ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();

        boolean edited = false;

        for (int i=0; i<answerContainer.length; i++){
            boolean errorFlag = false;
            LinearLayout ansView = answerContainer[i];

            String dqId = (String)questionContainer[i].getTag(R.id.dq_id);
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "dq id:"+dqId);  
                JSONStringer editJson = new JSONStringer().array();
                JSONStringer addJson = new JSONStringer().array();

                boolean addFlag = false;
                boolean editFlag = false;

                for(int j=0; j<ansView.getChildCount(); j++){
                    //Log.i(TAG, "text no.:"+j);
                    EditText ansText = (EditText)ansView.getChildAt(j);
                    if (//!ansText.getText().toString().isEmpty() &&
                     (boolean)ansText.getTag(R.id.edit_flag) == true){
                        //Log.d(TAG, ansText.getText().toString());
                        edited = true;
                        if (!((String)ansText.getTag(R.id.da_id)).isEmpty()){//edit
                            editJson
                                .object()
                                    .key(SupremeDB.DANCE_ANS_ID)
                                    .value(ansText.getTag(R.id.da_id))                                      
                                    .key(SupremeDB.DANCE_ANS_CONTENT)
                                    .value(URLEncoder.encode(ansText.getText().toString(), "UTF-8"))
                                .endObject();

                            editFlag = true;                                
                        } else {//add
                            addJson
                                .object()
                                    .key(SupremeDB.DANCE_ANS_CONTENT)
                                    .value(URLEncoder.encode(ansText.getText().toString(), "UTF-8"))
                                .endObject();

                            addFlag = true;
                        }
                    }                       
                }
                editJson.endArray();    
                addJson.endArray(); 

                if (editFlag){                                      
                    Log.d(TAG, editJson.toString());
                    AddEditProcessor editSave = new AddEditProcessor(controller.bniRootUrl+
                                                                    controller.folderOneToOne+
                                                                    controller.folderOnetoOneDance+
                                                                    controller.fileEdit, activity);
                    editSave.execute(new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_ID, danceId),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_QUE_ID, dqId+""),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_DATE, datePickerOpener.getText().toString()+" "+timeText.getText().toString()),
                            new BasicNameValuePair("answers", editJson.toString()));
                    if (!editSave.get()){
                        Log.e(TAG, "error occur at edit save");
                        errorFlag = true;
                    }
                }

                if (addFlag){                                   
                    Log.d(TAG, addJson.toString());
                    AddEditProcessor addSave = new AddEditProcessor(controller.bniRootUrl+
                            controller.folderOneToOne+
                            controller.folderOnetoOneDance+
                            controller.fileAdd, activity);
                    addSave.execute(new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_ID, danceId),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_QUE_ID, dqId+""),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_DATE, datePickerOpener.getText().toString()),
                            new BasicNameValuePair("answers", addJson.toString()));
                    if (!addSave.get()){
                        Log.e(TAG, "error occur at add save");
                        errorFlag = true;
                    }
                }

                if (errorFlag){
                    errorList.add("q"+(i+1));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (errorList.size()>0){
            StringBuilder errMsgBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            errMsgBuilder.append("儲存發生錯誤於: ");
            for(int n=0; n<errorList.size(); n++){
                errMsgBuilder.append(errorList.get(n)).append(",");
            }
            errMsgBuilder.deleteCharAt(errMsgBuilder.length()-1);
            Toast.makeText(activity, errMsgBuilder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if ((boolean)datePickerOpener.getTag(R.id.edit_flag) ==true || (boolean)timeText.getTag(R.id.edit_flag) ==true || edited == true){
                boolean successFlag = true;

                if ((boolean)datePickerOpener.getTag(R.id.edit_flag) ==true || (boolean)timeText.getTag(R.id.edit_flag) ==true){
                    AddEditProcessor saveOneToOne = new AddEditProcessor(controller.bniRootUrl+controller.folderOneToOne+controller.folderOneToOneCalendar+controller.fileEdit, activity);
                    saveOneToOne.execute(
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_ID, danceId),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.USER_ID, user.getUserId()),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_DATE, datePickerOpener.getText().toString()+" "+timeText.getText().toString()),
                            new BasicNameValuePair(SupremeDB.DANCE_MEMBER_ID, (String)datePickerOpener.getTag(R.id.dance_member_id))
                            );
                    try {
                        if (saveOneToOne.get()){
                            LoadingProcessor load = new LoadingProcessor(controller);
                            LoadProcessor loadProcessor = load.new LoadProcessor(SupremeDB.ONE_TO_ONE_TABLE);
                            loadProcessor.execute();

                            JSONObject jsonObject = loadProcessor.get();
                            if (jsonObject != null){

                                load.loadIntoDB(SupremeDB.ONE_TO_ONE_TABLE, jsonObject);

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_read_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                successFlag = false;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_sd_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            successFlag = false;
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (edited){
                    LoadingProcessor load = new LoadingProcessor(controller);
                    LoadProcessor loadProcessor = load.new LoadProcessor(SupremeDB.ONE_TO_ONE_ANSWER_TABLE);
                    loadProcessor.execute();

                    try {               
                        JSONObject jsonObject = loadProcessor.get();                
                        if (jsonObject != null){

                            load.loadIntoDB(SupremeDB.ONE_TO_ONE_ANSWER_TABLE, jsonObject);                         


                        } else {                        
                            Toast.makeText(activity, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_read_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            successFlag = false;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (successFlag){
                    Toast.makeText(activity, getResources().getString(R.string.msg_saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    activity.onBackPressed();
                }
            }
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
              dialog.dismiss();            
            }
        }).start();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: what is your "activity" variable?

Comment: @Simon post your entire asynctask

Comment: Because of the failure, I have change the code not using asynctask to pop up progressdialog. Maybe the code is a bit misdirecting, I have edited it.

Comment: @Simon can you remove everything except the showing of dialog and check if it is displayed

Comment: @Simon For network operation your code is bad. Use `AsyncTask` at where in `onPostExecute()` method you can update your UI elements.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I remove all other codes and add sleep(5000) it shows the progressdialog.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA thanks for your comment, it is quite complicated......I will try to modify

Comment: @Simon you are one step closer to solve this, add a block of code at a time and check.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin the progressdialog pops up just because I add sleep(5000). When I put the codes inside the thread, the error comes out again
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: @Simon post what have you done

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin putting the from `ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();...` into the thread

Comment: @Simon are you putting the progressdialog in a thread?

Comment: tried both put and not put into thread, still the same error comes out

Comment: @Simon post the entire class code you are currently using

Answer (score -1):

```
Probably you are getting error because of the thread in which you are using the context of the activity.    

I would like to refer that You should use the AsyncTask instead of a normal thread. In AsyncTask there is a method onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() which are executing on the main thread and there is a method doInBackground() which will execute on background so that you can easily implement the long live process.
```

> [as like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660)

Comment: dialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext()); have you try this ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a guessing place.